# Unable to implement an library (flexselect) in cakephp2 due to errors

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I tried to add the flex select in Cakephp2's ctp file and got the following error. How will I be able to solve this issue? I googled around and tried but no solution that helped. I would love to hear from you!

```
  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexselect is not a function
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):557)
        at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
        at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
        at HTMLDocument.H (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
```

index line 557 refers to the following code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select.special-flexselect").flexselect({ hideDropdownOnEmptyInput: true });
    $("select.flexselect").flexselect();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: You need to include the JS file that has the `flexselect` plugin in your page. If you check the homepage of the plugin it even shows you how: http://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the provided JS-plugin-file 'JQuery-FlexSelect' brings *before* calling the function.

Best practice would be to include the 'FlexSelect'-file followed by your own script file right at the end of your body tag to reduce loading times. Remember to include JQuery before including your plugin as well, since it's a dependency.

```
[...]
<body>
    [...]

    <script src="path/to/your/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/flex/flexselect.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/your/script.js"></script>
[...]
```